# Identical structures in interfaces

Tags: go, dependency-injection, interface, type-conversion

I have two separated modules, let's call them

1. FileSaver
2. VideoFileProducer

---

I want to separate them as much as possible, they shouldn't know about each others' structures and interfaces.

FileSaver module has these interfaces and structs: https://play.golang.org/p/OHObk0EPlG
VideoFileProducer module has these interfaces and structs: 
https://play.golang.org/p/iBOOaSPLc0

As you can see:

- `fileSaver.File` is identical to the `videoFileProducer.VideoFile`
- `fileSaver.FileSaver` interface is identical to the `videoFileProducer.VideoFileSaver` interface (the difference is that the method `SaveFile` receives different_but_identical structures: `File` and `VideoFile`)
- `fileSaver.fileSaverImpl` implements the `fileSaver.FileSaver` interface
- `videoFileSaver.NewVideoFileProducer` receives implementation of `videoFileSaver.VideoFileSaver` interface

In Main package I want to Inject FileSaver into the VideoFileProducer:
https://play.golang.org/p/8B1iMCLLBE

Of course I'm getting an error (https://play.golang.org/p/Eqr2ylKiQ6):

> FileSaver does not implement VideoFileSaver (wrong type for SaveFile method)
>
> have SaveFile(File)
>
> want SaveFile(VideoFile)

These two structures are identical, we can easily convert VideoFile to File and File to VideoFile, but anyway they have different types.

---

In short I want to create FileSaver interface in Main package, cast it to VideoFileSaver and send it to the VideoFileProducer.

Or somehow to adapt FileSaver interface to be used as VideoFileSaver interface.

---

### Working solution #1 (anonymous structure)

https://play.golang.org/p/NJRUCCp2xS

This solution uses anonymous structure and it can be too big to declare it as anonymous in so many places (I've got only one method but there can be many of them in real application).

---

### Not working approach #1 (Fileable/VideoFileable interfaces)

https://play.golang.org/p/0rP4nn7j-T

I've tried to make the structure (File,VideoFile) to implement the interface that has a method for conversion it to the specified anonymous structure, but haven't succeeded.

---

### Not working approach #1 (interface{})

https://play.golang.org/p/8Q1KHhzl_g

Previous approach but with using interface{}. Not working because of Interface Assertion (underlying types are different)

Is there any way to convert interface directly to other type than the underlying one (without using reflection)?

---

### Working solution #2 (Fileable/VideoFileable + interface{})

https://play.golang.org/p/xacNEjFG7D

I've combined last two approaches and added the using of switch to check "is underlying interface identical to the required one". So now I can to use VideoFileable as Fileable.

However it's not the best-looking solution and I'm still looking for a solution which uses as less anonymous structures and interface{} as possible.

---

### Working solution #3 (Fileable/VideoFileable + reflection)

https://play.golang.org/p/4UPEmNkG-E

Converting VideoFileable to Fileable

---

### Working solution #4  (interface{} + reflection)

https://play.golang.org/p/AneYQVm2Gc

VideoFile converts directly to File

---

---

I'm not satisfied with any of the solutions above and still looking for something more clean.

Comment: It seems that the problem stems from the fact that these two packages have to be so similar that they seem like they do know about eachother by design but you want them not to. The "VideoFile" struct and "File" struct have to be the same for them to work properly yet they are in separate packages/modules. If you were to add a new property to the VideoFile struct like "Director string" then your working solutions fail to save the proper fields or you would have to add that property in the "File" package which negates that fact they should not know about eachother.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. These packages are really way too similar and making additional package with common model would be the best way. Anyway I'm just curious if there are any way to do as I've described, especially when everything works with anonymous struct way.

Comment: I think you need to model things with the File package first and then utilize the Video package to extend from it by importing that package. That is a very acceptable design choice if you do it that way.

Comment: @JoeMoe1984 "If you were to add a new property to the VideoFile struct like "Director string" then your working solutions fail to save the proper fields" If we are using Anonymous struct solution, we will get an error on compilation step coz VideoFile can't be cast to struct {Name string  Size int}. I want to find something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a solution that, as I think, satisfies requirements.

It's just an implementation of Adapter pattern. On high level of module hierarchy we create new Service that implements the VideoFileSaver interfaces and calls the FileSaver interface in it.

*VideoFileSaver* --(VideoFile)--> Adapter --(File)--> *FileSaver*

https://play.golang.org/p/fO_ML6veWt

**Pros of this solution**: Extremely low coupling of modules, File struct can even be absolutely different from VideoFile if we add additional logic in adapter

**Cons of this solution**: High complexity

I **wouldn't recommend** you to use this solution. It just has satisfied my curiosity but in real project instead of it you should (mostly) use the more simple way to do such things - like creating a common structure in the third module (on the low level of hierarchy). As has been described by weberc2.

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `VideoFile` struct and use the `File` struct in both places. If you don't want a `video`->`file` dependency, you'll have to extract the common types (`File` and `FileSaver`) into a third package (this works for the same reason as your anonymous struct solution--the "definition" of the struct is accessible to both packages).

**types package**

```
package types

type File struct {
    Name string
    Size int
}

type FileSaver interface {
    SaveFile(File)
}
```

**file package**

```
package file

import (
    "fmt"
    "types"
)

type fileSaverImpl struct{}

func (fs fileSaverImpl) SaveFile(f types.File) {
    fmt.Println(f.Name, f.Size)
}

func NewFileSaver() types.FileSaver {
    return fileSaverImpl{}
}
```

**video package**

```
package video

import "types"

type VideoFileProducer struct{}

// NOTE: This function title is misleading; it doesn't actually
// create a `VideoFileProducer`, but instead it makes a new file
// and saves it with the provisioned `FileSaver`.
func NewVideoFileProducer(fileSaver types.FileSaver) {
    fileSaver.SaveFile(types.File{Name: "Video", Size: 256})
}
```

**main package**

```
package main

import (
    "file"
    "video"
)

func main() {
    NewVideoFileProducer(file.NewFileSaver())
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP doesn't want any of the packages to import one another. "they shouldn't know about each others' structures and interfaces". Importing the File package would mean that the Video package knows about the Files structures and interfaces.

Comment: @JoeMoe1984 Thanks, it's not clear what the OP's requirements are here, so I added a sentence about extracting mutual dependencies into a third package.

Comment: But it will lead to tight-coupling between to modules. I wanted only Main to know about both packages. In short I want to create FileSaver interface in Main package, cast it to VideoFileSaver and send it to the VideoFileProducer.

Comment: @i.van Can you elaborate on your coupling concern? In particular, why is it not addressed by extracting the `File` struct and `FileSaver` interface into a third package that the `file` and `video` packages depend on?

Comment: @weberc2 I've got two packages that doesn't know about each other. One says "Hey I have interface implementation that has a method that produces the structure that is defined in me", the other one says "I'm just waiting for someone who have implements the described interface with method to produce the structure that is defined in me". I don't know if it possible in Go, I'm just curious about it, especially after seeing that Anonymous struct solution works fine.

Comment: @i.van I updated my answer. I think this is the best possible solution given the parameters of the question. That said, the parameters themselves suggest a deeper architectural problem--delving into that is probably outside the scope of this Q/A, so feel free to elaborate in your Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/55efmc/casting_between_interfaces_that_describes_same/

Comment: @weberc2 thanks, I've answered in the Reddit post. Making common structure is the really is the most popular decision. But I want to reduce outside dependencies as much as possible. I think, I'm looking for something like Adapter pattern (but with using the language specs)